# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49 error - NFA Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, indexoutofboundsexception, nfa

I am writing code to simulate Non-deterministic finite automata. The program asks the user to input the NFA, followed by strings to test whether they belong to the NFA or not.
However, the program keeps crashing due to this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49

I've tried a lot to see if and where there's an overflow occurring, but I just can't figure it out.

My class NFA:

```
public static class NFA
{
    int numStates;
    int alphabetSize;
    char[] alphabets;
    LinkedList[] transitionTable;
    boolean[] isFinal;
    NFA()
    {
        numStates = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of States: "));
        alphabetSize = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of Alphabets, including epsilon transition 'e': "));
        alphabets = new char[alphabetSize];
        alphabets[0] = 'e';
        for(int i=1;i<alphabetSize;i++)
        {
            alphabets[i] = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter alphabet "+i+": ")).charAt(0);
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(alphabets[j]+" "+alphabets[i]);
                if(alphabets[j]==alphabets[i])
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Alphabet '"+alphabets[i]+"' already exists in the alphabet space! Enter some other alphabet.");
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }    

        }  
        transitionTable = new LinkedList[numStates];
        for(int i=0;i<numStates;i++)
        {
            transitionTable[i] = new LinkedList();
            int ch = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to add any transition(s) for state s"+i+"? (Y=1, N=0)"));

            while(ch == 1)
            {
                String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter transition for State"+i+" in the format 'alphabet-stateNumber':");
                transitionTable[i].add(data);
                System.out.println("S"+i+": "+transitionTable[i]);
                ch = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to add more transitions for state s"+i+"? (Y=1, N=0)"));
            }

        }
        isFinal = new boolean[numStates];
         for(int k=0;k<numStates;k++)
        {
            int ans = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is s"+k+" an accept state?(1=Y, 0=N)"));
            if(ans == 1)
            {
                isFinal[k] = true;
            }
            else isFinal[k] = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean accepts(String stringName) {
        if(stringName.equals(""))
        {
            if(isFinal[0]) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        int startState = 0;
        return recursiveAccept(stringName, startState, 0);
    }

    private boolean recursiveAccept(String stringName, int currState, int currIndex)
    {
        System.out.println("\t\tcurrIndex:"+currIndex+"\tlength() == "+stringName.length());
        if(currIndex == stringName.length())
        {
            if(isFinal[currState])
                return true;
            else if(transitionTable[currState].size() == 0)
            {
                return false;
                //String[] s = (String[]) transitionTable[currState].toArray();
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<transitionTable[currState].size();i++)
                {
                    if((""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(0) == 'e')
                    {
                        System.out.println("\t\tEntered line 114");
                        if(recursiveAccept(stringName, (""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(2), currIndex))
                            return true;
                    }
                }                   
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(transitionTable[currState].size()==0) //&& currIndex<(stringName.length()-1))
            return false;
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<transitionTable[currState].size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("\t\tLoop at line 129...linked list element : "+transitionTable[currState].get(i));
                if((""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(0) == 'e')
                {
                    if(recursiveAccept(stringName, (""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(2), currIndex))
                        return true;
                }
                else if((""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(0) == stringName.charAt(currIndex))
                {
                    if(recursiveAccept(stringName, (""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(2), currIndex+1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    NFA objectName = new NFA();

    int choice = 1;
    while (choice == 1 )
    {
    String stringName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter String :");
    //String stringName = "111";
    if(objectName.accepts(stringName))
        System.out.print(stringName+" is accepted!");
    else System.out.print(stringName+" not accepted!");

    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter more?(1=Y, 0=N)"));
    }
}
```

Any help in understanding the cause of the problem would be appreciated.
Also, I'm a rookie at java, so my implementations might not be the best.

Comment: What code is present at line 49 ?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with line 49. Even if i change the code and add more blank lines, the exception message still shows 49.
Maybe it's some 49 in some other file that i don't know about

Comment: I ran your code in my machine. Only change is I removed the "static" from class NFA. I didnot get arrayIndexOutOfBound. Only exception I got was NumberFormatException when I entered text in place of number.

Comment: When i remove "static" from class NFA on my machine, it gives an error in main, saying that NFA ObjectName is a non-static variable and cannot be referenced from a static context. 
FYI, I'm using Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code has some problems:

```
if(recursiveAccept(stringName, (""+transitionTable[currState].get(i)).charAt(2), currIndex))
    return true;
```

You simply take the third character of the string. I assume the `currState` can be 10, 11 etc.

Also I'd like to mention the following code:

```
String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter transition for State"+i+" in the format 'alphabet-stateNumber':");
transitionTable[i].add(data);
```

No checks are done that `data` is correct.

Anyway, the general advice is to debug the code to reproduce an error and find out why one of your automate arrays is being referenced at index greater than the number of states.

Comment: Actually, I'm assuming no fault from the user side. Transitions are entered as `1-2`, if an alphabet 1 takes the current state to state 2. Hence, the third character is 2. That's what i meant.

and since i was testing the program myself, I haven't put any checks yet.

Comment: @bhatGautam Then the only thing I can recommend is debugging and saving all the input that cause the exception. As your program is single-threaded, you should have no problems reproducing it.

Comment: The only time I haven't got an exception is when I input the empty string. And that's because the condition is hard coded. :/

Could there be something wrong with the fact that i'm calling a recursive function for every possible transition in the transition table?

Comment: Well, the fact of using recursion itself, most likely leads to `StackOverflowError` rather than yours. I think you have some problem with performing transition somewhere. Try debugger, really.